# SVG D3JS animation: how to make an arc " self-drawing"?

Tags: d3.js, svg, css-animations

I have draw half of a circumference using D3JS, and I'd like it to start to self-draw when the webpage is loaded. how can I achieve this? this is the svg arc:

javascript:

```
var width = 960,
    height = 500;
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width",width)
    .attr("height",height)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

var path = svg.append("path")
    .attr("d", d3.svg.arc()
    .innerRadius(height / 4)
    .outerRadius(height / 3)
    .startAngle(0)
    .endAngle(Math.PI));
```

CSS:

```
path {
  cursor: pointer;
  fill: #00338D;
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 1;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: animate the stroke-dasharray property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this either by css using plain transition or `keyframes` OR javascript using `getTotalLength` combined with `getPointAtLength` of which the path element inherits from `SVGGraphicsElement` interface.

For older browsers or if you have an end-marker in the path, javascript solution will be better, on the other hand css transitions make use of `stroke-dasharray` and `stroke-dashoffset` properties.

To trigger the drawing action, wrap your function with an `onload` handler of the window.

See this [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ibowankenobi/pes0bydg/):

Above is a general solution. For your d3 example you can use arc tweens as well:

```
var width = 960,
    height = 500;
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width",width)
    .attr("height",height)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

var path = svg.append("path")
        .transition()
    .attrTween("d",function(){
      var _f = d3.svg.arc().innerRadius(height / 4).outerRadius(height / 3).startAngle(0);
      var interpolator = d3.interpolateNumber(0,Math.PI);
      return function(t){
        return (_f.endAngle(interpolator(t))())
      }
    })
    .duration(2000);
```

[**WORKING FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ibowankenobi/b57uLeoz/).

Wrap the above script in an `onload` handler. Like **[this](http://jsfiddle.net/ibowankenobi/b57uLeoz/15/)**.